# Spring cloud server Client does not see properties git uri

Tags: spring, windows, macos, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I have server and client, made by referring https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/ But my client does not run, cause

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'http://localhost:8888'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.resolve(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.lambda$resolve$1(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:126)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:115)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLocationResolvers.resolve(ConfigDataLocationResolvers.java:107)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolve(ConfigDataImporter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:121)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processInitial(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:242)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:100)
    at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:86)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:82)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:63)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:117)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:362)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300)
    at bobryakov.dmitry.ConfigurationClientApplication.main(ConfigurationClientApplication.java:9)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:214)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:125)
    ... 30 common frames omitted
```

As i understand, it because of client doesn't see it's files in server `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri` or `spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations` or `spring.cloud.config.server.native.searchLocations` I tried different notations:

```
file:///C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config
file:///C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config/
file://C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config
C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config
C:\\\\Users\\\\u_m167y\\\\Desktop\\\\config\\\\
```

But nothing works. I have git repo in that dir with .git and `a-bootiful-client.properties` In client i have `spring.application.name=a-bootiful-client` What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need an extra "/" in the file URL if it is absolute with a drive prefix `(for example,file:///${user.home}/config-repo)`

Refer [spring-cloud-config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html)

**EDIT :**

The above link has following listing, whihc shows a recipe for creating the git repository in the preceding example:

```
$ cd $HOME
$ mkdir config-repo
$ cd config-repo
$ git init .
$ echo info.foo: bar > application.properties
$ git add -A .
$ git commit -m "Add application.properties"
```

Comment: Already tried file:///C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config
Still not works

Comment: Checked on MacOs, same problem

Comment: EDIT: I did this point, in my C:/Users/u_m167y/Desktop/config I have git rep iwth only 1 file- a-bootiful-client.properties